# Deleting entry from databse by deselcting checkbox in php

Tags: php, mysql

I have list of checkboxes on web page. What I want is , after deselcting checkbox particular record from database should get deleted accordingly in php.

Comment: Have you tried anything yourself?  Show some code of what you have attempted.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You'll need to use some javascript to "listen" for the uncheck action on each checkbox. You can then use AJAX to delete the record from the database on the fly, and use jQuery make the record disappear visually from the webpage, all without reloading.

Comment: can you please provide me the link to use AJAX for this question.